# How to switch API with a model file on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a movie reviews website and setting multi languages translation.
Because of the translation, Movie API is needed to be switched to each language.
Now the API is defined on a model file though, I don't have any ideas that switching API.

Movie model

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty
  self.primary_key = "id"
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :comments
  

  default_options.update(verify: false)
  default_params api_key: '#API key', language: "en-EN" #swtiching needed for other languages.                 
  format :json
　~
end
```

Firstly, I tried using `if` and `request.path.include?` to place URL with English or other languages. But `request` command is not allowed to use on a model file.
How can I switching it? Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method in your Model that accepts language as a parameter, and call that method from the Controller.

Comment: I created methods that define API with each language and used them on the Controller, which makes the website switch API languages. Thank you for your comment.